# How to allocate a memory with execute permissions?

Tags: c++, c

I want to allocate a memory with execute permissions.
So I use mprotect to change the permissions.. To get a page aligned memory I use a `valloc` function.

```
void * temp = (void *) valloc(x);
```

and then

```
if( mprotect(temp, BLOCK_SIZE, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE |PROT_EXEC))) {
   exit(-1);
}
```

Now I want to add more memory to this allocated block. Hence I use a `realloc` function.

```
void * new_temp = (void *) realloc(temp, 1024);
```

Will this reallocate automatically change the permissions of the allocated memory to the ones I had set earlier ?? In case `realloc` moves the entire block to a different location, what be the permissions of allocated memory earlier and the newly allocated memory?

Should `mprotect` be used again to get execute permissions memory. And is there a API to `realloc` on page size boundary like `valloc`. ?

Comment: You should tag this with the appropriate OS, as this is more of a OS than language question.

Comment: valloc() is a legacy BSD function removed in the SUSv3. Presume some POSIX OS like Linux or BSD.

Comment: @David: Not really, this stuff is supported by both Windoze and Linux (other OS do not exist), and the API only varies where POSIX has not standardized.

Answer (score 4):

Try allocating a new region with another `valloc`, and copying the old contents across. Better yet, stop using the deprecated `valloc`, and replace it with either `posix_memalign` calls, or directly `mmap` for very large allocations. Using `mremap` you could effectively `realloc` page-aligned memory regions.

Answer (score 1):

> Should mprotect be used again to get execute permissions memory.

Virtual memory is organized in pages. `mprotect()` changes the flags on all pages in the given block of virtual memory. It is independent from the actual memory allocation. IOW, you have to call mprotect() again after realloc to reapply the permissions. And you have to call it again for the whole region, since `realloc()` can instead of extending the existing block return pointer to a new one.

Thinking about it now, I think one might need to call `mprotect()` before the `realloc()`  to remove the exec permissions from the old memory region. `malloc()`/`realloc()` are libc functions for management of memory inside the application's virtual memory, while `mprotect()` is a syscall operating independently on the application's virtual memory itself.

> And is there a API to realloc on page size boundary like valloc. ?

Very much doubt it.

In memory allocation intensive application, `realloc()` is rarely capable of extending the existing block and often ends up allocating new block + memcpy() + free old block. If `realloc()` performance was acceptable before, than its hand-coded version (taking stricter alignment into account) should be fine too.

BTW, POSIXv6 has a new function called `posix_memalign()`. [valloc's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/valloc) is an interesting read, mostly why one shouldn't use the valloc() in the first place.

P.S. Also you can always use standard POSIX function to find the page size `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);` and align memory buffer yourself. Obviously you have to allocate `new_size+(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)-1)` bytes to have sufficient memory to realign the pointer.

Comment: You definitely don't want to remove EXEC permission for a page just because *one* buffer in that page no longer needs it.  Unless you only ever have one executable buffer dynamically allocated, so you know that there isn't another executable buffer in the same page.